# $P(X = n) = pq^{n-1}$ where p, q > 0 and p + q = 1. Find Var(X) using generating function.

Tags: probability

$P(X = n) = pq^{n-1}$ where $p, q > 0$ and $p + q = 1$. Find ${\tt Var}(X)$ using generating function.

First I found $E(X)$:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^n = 1/(1-q) - 1 = q/(1-q)$$ then differentiate

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty nq^{n-1} = 1/(1-q) + q/(1-q)^2 = 1/(1-q)^2$$

Then multiplying by p you have $p/(1-q)^2 = 1/p = E(X)$.

You can differentiate again to obtain

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n(n-1)q^{n-2} = 1/(1-q)^3$$

then $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2q^{n-2} = 1/(1-q)^2 + 1/(1-q)^3$$

$pq$ times above sum = $q/p + q/p^2 = (1-p^2)/p^2$

I must have went wrong, because $Var(X) = E(X^2) - [E(X)]^2 = -1$.

Next, using the generating function, 
$$G(\alpha) = E(\alpha ^x)$$ 
$$G'(1) = E(X)$$ 
$$G''(1) = E(X(X-1))$$.

$$G(\alpha) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \alpha^npq^{n-1} = p/q \sum_{n=1}^\infty (\alpha q)^n = p\alpha/(1-q\alpha)$$

$$G'(\alpha) = p/(1-q\alpha) + pq\alpha/(1-q\alpha)^2$$

$$G'(1) = 1/p = E(X)$$

So I'm fairly confident I have $E(X)$.

$$G''(\alpha) = 2pq/(1-q\alpha)^2 + pq^2\alpha/(1-q\alpha)^3$$

$$G''(1) = E(X(X-1)) = E(X^2) - E(X) = 2q/p + q^2/p^2$$

So add $E(X) = 1/p$ to get $E(X^2)$:

$$2q/p + 1/p + q^2/p^2 = (5p - p^2 + 1)/p^2$$

Then subtract $[E(X)]^2 = 1/p^2$ and you have

$$(5p - p^2)/p^2 = (5-p)/p = Var(X)$$

Not sure about this.
Please let me know where the errors are in both methods, and provide the solutions.

EDIT:
Tried again with generating function, think I got it this time:

$$G'(\alpha) = p/(1-q\alpha) + pq\alpha/(1-q\alpha)^2$$
$$G''(\alpha) = pq/(1-q\alpha)^2 + pq/(1-q\alpha)^2 + 2pq^2\alpha/(1-q\alpha)^3$$
$$G''(1) = 2q/p + 2q^2/p^2 = (2pq + 2q^2)/p^2 = 2q(p+q)/p^2 = 2(1-p)/p^2 = E(X(X-1))$$
For $Var(X)$, add $E(X)$ and subtract $[E(X)]^2$:
$$(2(1-p) + p - 1)/p^2 = (1 - p)/p^2 = Var(X)$$
Please let me know if this is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have made several mistakes in the first method. The derivative of $\frac 1 {(1-q)^{2}}$ is $-\frac 2 {(1-q)^{3}}$. Also you have used the formula for $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} nq^{n-1}$ when you actually have $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} nq^{n-2}$. If you redo your calculations you should be able to get the same answer by both methods.

Comment: Please see my new attempt using the generating function.